# Magento 2 Change Product Price

Tags: magento2, product, category-products, sales

I am working on magento 2.2.6  sale extension and I want to change the price of the product by subtracting the sales price from it.As you know a single product is shown on multiple pages and categories on a store i.e(product-page,categories,search).
I'm looking for a way to change product prices as per sales.Please Guide me about from where I should Start ...?

Answer (score 3):

For starting purpose I suggest you to see `getFinalPrice()` method in class `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product`

You can create a test after plugin for same and modify the price as per your requirement.

**For Example**

```
    public function afterGetFinalPrice($product, $result)
    {
        return $result - 2;
    }
```